# Reverse SSH tunnel failing to open local port on remote host?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, sshd

I am using the following reverse SSH command to try and open up a reverse SSH tunnel on a CentOS 7 host back to a Debian 10 host.

```
ssh -p 20000 -NR 20050:localhost:22 user@ipaddress
```

When I try this command I get the following warning:

> Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 20050

It appears the SSH connection is made, but port 20050 is failing to open on the remote host. I am pretty sure that port 20050 is not already open on the remote host. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Turns out the authorized key set on the remote host had `no-port-forwarding` option set. I removed this and now it works fine.

Comment: You'll need to wait a couple of days, but when you get the chance please do accept your own answer. That'll prevent the question from popping up from the "Unanswered" -queue in the future.